# Reading one-column file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read the following file into a pandas dataframe :

```
(dataA
0   
400 
2800
9200
5600
2000
8400
4800
1200
7600
4000
400
6800
)
(dataB
30
30
30
30
30
30
20
500
30
50
330
530
930
)
```

The objective being to have something as this :

```
dataA dataB
0     30
400   30
2800  30
9200  30
5600  30
2000  30
8400  20
4800  500
1200  30
7600  50
4000  330
400   530
6800  930
```

I know this can be done by reading the file line by line, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to have it read by pandas (as read_csv for example).
This is because there are lots of files similar to this one and the post-processing is already automatized for that type of data.

Comment: does your actual dataframe have `(` in the data?

Comment: Nope, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the fact that you have parethisis that break the columns apart we can create two new indexes and unstack your columns.

It's important you read your file with `header=None`

```
df = pd.read_excel(...,header=None)

s = df[0].str.contains('\(',regex=True)

df1 = df.set_index([s.cumsum(), df.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount()]).unstack(0)
#additional clean up
df1 = df1.replace('\(|\)','',regex=True).replace('',np.nan).dropna().droplevel(0,1)
```

---

```
#setup columns.
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0]
df1 = df1.iloc[1:]



print(df1)
0  dataA dataB
1   0       30
2   400     30
3   2800    30
4   9200    30
5   5600    30
6   2000    30
7   8400    20
8   4800   500
9   1200    30
10  7600    50
11  4000   330
12   400   530
13  6800   930
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need to create dataframe from a **dictionary** of **lists**:

1. Import pandas library:

   ```
    import pandas as pd
   ```
2. Create a dictionary from your list:

   ```
   data = { 'dataA': [0,400 ,2800,9200,5600,2000,8400,4800,1200,7600,4000,400,6800],
        'dataB': [30,30,30,30,30,30,20,500,30,50,330,530,930]}
   ```
3. Create your dataframe:

   ```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   ```
4. Call your data frame:

   ```
    df
   ```

Overally, you can see the total code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'dataA': [0,400 ,2800,9200,5600,2000,8400,4800,1200,7600,4000,400,6800],
        'dataB': [30,30,30,30,30,30,20,500,30,50,330,530,930]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

and the output will be:

```
    dataA   dataB
0   0       30
1   400     30
2   2800    30
3   9200    30
4   5600    30
5   2000    30
6   8400    20
7   4800    500
8   1200    30
9   7600    50
10  4000    330
11  400     530
12  6800    930
```

---

If you are willing to **not** see the number of rows in your dataframe, add this code at the end:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

The output will be:

```
 dataA  dataB
     0     30
   400     30
  2800     30
  9200     30
  5600     30
  2000     30
  8400     20
  4800    500
  1200     30
  7600     50
  4000    330
   400    530
  6800    930
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all?

Comment: why do you think my answer does not reply the question??

Comment: because it doesn't answer the question.. all you've done is created a dataframe from a list and printed it?

Comment: Yes, Whenever he/sh wants to read data, definitely needs a data file like csv,  xlsx, or create a data list to read data and because he/she did not refer to any files I did create a list in dictionary to access data.